# Split the string into words

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

how to split a string into words of 2 letters. Like given string is "HelloThere" now i want to make it ["He","ll","oT","he","re"]. Please help to code that in python.

Comment: `ans = [word[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(word),2)]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
yourList = []
yourString = "HelloThere"
while yourString:
    yourList.append(yourString[:2])
    yourString = yourString[2:]
```

If you print yourList, you will get the result.